# Building ROS on Fedora 15

Tags: ros, rosinstall, rosmake, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build ROS on Fedora 15, and I get an error with rosmake:

```
Detected ros_comm bootstrapping it too.
  File "/home/user/ros/ros/bin/rosmake", line 46
    print "Rospack failed to build" 
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I looked into the issue, this is invalid syntax in 3.0 or higher, but I'm running 2.7. If I make my default python 3.2, then rosinstall doesn't even run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rosinstall", line 4, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

Is this a Fedora issue? Is this a python issue? How can I solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10107/building-ros-on-fedora-15/) by [Skinkworks](https://answers.ros.org/users/620/skinkworks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2011-05-30**:
At least, I suspect it not to be a general fedora issue, I built ROS on Fedora 12 with python 2.6.2 and never saw that. But I really want to upgrade, and now as 15 is released, I hope there is a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a python 2.6 vs 2.7 issue I'm pretty sure.  Patches to rosmake are trickling in.

---

Originally posted by [Straszheim](https://answers.ros.org/users/44/straszheim/) with karma: 426 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2